# Looking for a tool to examine a PCIe Device tree

Tags: pci, pci-e

I am looking for a tool that can show the device tree for pci express devices including switches. I am trying to examine the topology of the pcie from root port down to debug some issues we are having with device bandwidths. Is there anything like that available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lspci on linux.
Sample usage can be found in man page. I generally use:

## lspci -t

To have a tree view.

In windows I think there's tool called pcitree but I never used it.